# C# Code Injection?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I have a bunch of functions that I use OVER AND OVER again all over the place in random areas. And also some getters and setters.

For example just stuff like this:

```
public GameObject GameObjectCache 
{ 
    get 
    { 
        if (gameObjectCache == null)
            gameObjectCache = this.gameObject;
        return gameObjectCache; 
    } 
}
private GameObject gameObjectCache;

public Transform TransformCache 
{ 
    get 
    { 
        if (transformCache == null)
            transformCache = this.GetComponent<Transform>();
        return transformCache; 
    } 
}
private Transform transformCache;
```

This is for Unity if you can't tell.

What I would really like to do is take those functions and put them somewhere else. Then in my classes just do like

```
[TransformCache]
```

Some kind of one line tag and it would place the function, from elsewhere, inline into my class.

I know there is some complex way to do this with Mono.Cecil, which if anyone has a simple tutorial on that I'd love the link.

But is there an easier way than that? I know C and Objective-C, and even CG code have functions to do this. Is there anyway to do this in C# with ease?

Comment: Take a look at PostSharp: http://www.postsharp.net/

Comment: Do you need code injection or dependency injection? Take a look at MS Unity framework for managing dependency.

Comment: Not sure if MEF works in unity, but it will do what you are looking for.

Comment: Wouldn't a extension method suffice, unless some complex resolution is required

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this will help you or not, but how about wrapping some of these common things you want into a wrapper class, then just add the class to your other game object.  Something like

```
public class MyWrapper
{
   private GameObject parentGameObj;
   public MyWrapper(GameObject srcObj)
   {
      parentGameObj = srcObj;
   }

   public GameObject GameObjectCache 
   { 
       get 
       { 
           if (gameObjectCache == null)
               gameObjectCache = parentGameObj.gameObject;
           return gameObjectCache; 
       } 
   }
   private GameObject gameObjectCache;

   public Transform TransformCache 
   { 
       get 
       { 
           if (transformCache == null)
               transformCache = parentGameObj.GetComponent<Transform>();
           return transformCache; 
       } 
   }
   private Transform transformCache;
}
```

Then, in your classes that you will be using it

```
public class YourOtherClass : GameObject
{
   MyWrapper mywrapper;

   public Start()
   {
      // instantiate the wrapper object with the game object as the basis
      myWrapper = new MyWrapper(this);

      // then you can get the game and transform cache objects via
      GameObject cache1 = myWrapper.GameObjectCache;
      Transform tcache1 = myWrapper.TransformCache;
   }   
}
```

Sorry... in C++ you can derive from multiple classes which in essence COULD allow something like that.  The only other thing I can think of is looking into using Generics if your functions use repeated similar types via GetComponent() calls.

Comment: I've been doing this a lot. To some degree it can be good. But the method I describe in the opening post would allow for VASTLY cleaner code with how my classes end up going.

Comment: @techmage, revised note at bottom of answer.

Comment: I've started using this and actually quite like it. Thank you.